# Website Payment Pro outside US

Tags: paypal, payment, website-payment-pro

My current online shop use PayPal express checkout (for credit card too) to charge users.
Our surveys (and A/B testing) showed that they are willing to make am order in a fewer step and without going to Paypal website.

We are based in Hong Kong so *Website Payment Pro* with *DirectPayment* can't be used.
Do you any other solution that could fit (i.e same level of pricing) our needs.
Small transactions (< 100 USD), need to fully integrate the solution within our shop for credit card (no redirection to another website)?

We will probably keep paypal as a backup solution for customers without credit cards.

Comment: This question is not a programming question.

Comment: Although not directly programming related, this question still applies to tools used during webdevelopment in my opinion. Based on the answers, stunti is enabled to make a better choice for their checkout system, which will no-doubt require programming to integrate.

Comment: I'm a web developer, and sometimes non-programming related questions are in your way of building a great website. Payment system is now a big part of internet.

Comment: I suggest you read the FAQ, in particular the very first question/answer. Stack Overflow is a site for programming questions. It's not a site about building great web-sites or tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PayPal indeed does not offer WPP in Hong Kong, I see just three options:

- Open a business in US/UK/Canada where WPP is available;
- Use a standard credit card payment provider, not PayPal;
- Keep using WPS.

I'm afraid that none of these are the same level of pricing and benefits though. :(

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you have the same problems with [Google Checkout](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/index.html).

Comment: Unfortunately Google Checkout is only available in US and UK.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on:
http://www.avangate.com
http://www.epayment.ro

Comment: epayment is in Romanian and avantgate is a little bit pricey but I will investigate both of them.

Comment: Avangate and ePayment are the same company in fact but Avangate is the branch for outside Romania and for software developers!
Is there a problem if this company is located in Romania?

Comment: Not an issue. I just don't speak Romanian ;-) Will check Avantgate tho.

Comment: But they do speak English! Do you!?

Comment: Yes. That's why I will check out avantgate.